Disable quote-escaping in Dockerfile
I'm trying to run a PostgreSQL Command using PSQL in a Dockerfile to prepare a database for a dev environment. The command is something like psql -c "CREATE ...".
However, since Docker prefixes RUN Commands with /bin/sh -c the quotes in my psql command get weirdly escaped.
I already tried using a JSON list as the parameter, but it still escapes the characters and therefore returns result code 2.
This is my latest attempt:
RUN psql -c "CREATE ROLE root WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'root'"

Here you can see the docker build . error:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c psql -c \"CREATE ROLE root WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'root'\"" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2


Docker's logging doesn't represent its real command lines accurately. It is holding the psql -c ...etc... together as a single argument passed after -c, it's just doing logging naively (concatenating the argument list together with spaces without adding any quotes to readably display where the argument boundaries are) and not showing you that it's doing that.

Which is to say, you could make your code more explicit by using JSON form (RUN ["psql", "-c", "CREATE ROLE root WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'root'"]), but the problem you're having is unrelated so that won't actually be a solution.

...if you want to convince yourself of my assertion above, consider RUN set -x; psql -c "CREATE ROLE root WITH LOGIN SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'root'" -- that way the shell itself is responsible for adding quotes. (YMMV if it's alpine -- some versions have punted the same way as Docker does -- but if the sh in your container is provided by bash it'll display things unambiguously)

In any case you can't execute SQL statements in a Dockerfile: there's neither a database server nor persistent storage available during the image build.  The usual way to set up an initial user is with environment variables; the standard image's entrypoint script will create the user when the container is first run.
